# How to modify and use sklearn without installing?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, open-source

I want to make some changes to `sklearn` code and use the library without installing it.
I have downloaded the source from github and made the required changes.
But when I try to import a module, it gives me an error

```
No module named _check_build
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.
```

What should I do to use modified `sklearn` without installing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn#development

And what you really need is to install sklearn from source code. You must install sklearn before use it. Installation does not only means `pip install sklearn`, but also means you need to build it from source before use.